# Basement framing and furring

Tags: basement, framing

I have an unfinished basement that I would like to finish. Well it's sort of half finished by previous owner but I'm probably going to rip out and start from the scratch anyway.

So the house is on a slope such that half the basement is actually above grade, and where it's above grade the exterior wood frame sits on a concrete ledge that protrudes towards the basement interior. I would like to fur it such that wall is flush, and have few questions on it.

[Exterior wall photos](https://photos.app.goo.gl/oGw3SP7QrhKcS1UAA)[image]

If I do fur the wall so it goes over the ledge, do I need to fill the space with insulation? Wall is already insulated and drywalled, wondering whether I have to take it all down or can I just put insulation in front of existing drywall?

I see some part of the wall has already been furred out ([photos](https://photos.app.goo.gl/QKdASvGYKU63NMLy9) below). It looks like Styrofoam and wood panel. Is this an acceptable way to do it? Doesn't look right to me, but was wondering whether I can leave that alone.

[image]

As a second option can I chisel the ledge down? I imagine that would cause cracks and would be bad for the foundation support.

Comment: Your photos are blocked for me. Please embed at least one representative image in your post using the editor.

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: Really hard to get anything from those pictures.

Comment: Just wanted to know best way to make the concrete and the wall flush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see in the pictures is a few inches of concrete foundation wall protruding past the floor slab of your basement. The bottom plate framing for the walls is anchored to the top of the foundation. It is normal for the foundation wall (8in wide ?), to be a bit wider than the wall framing, (at 2x6 ?), which is why you require some furring to finish the inside.

Your options are to

- build out (e.g. fur out) the framing over the full height, such that new drywall paneling is plumb from ceiling to floor. You only need to add more insulation in the furred out space if the existing insulation is insufficient. White styrofoam is fine, but a compressed half-thick layer of fibreglass insulation will do as well. You should still use lumber strips, typ. horizontally every 2 feet in height, to provide support for the drywall panel.
- stop the drywall above the concrete foundation as in your first picture, and cover the bottom few vertical inches of concrete with baseboard / casing

I would not chisel as this is a lot of work, messy, and could leave cracks or gaps between the concrete foundation and bottom sill plate.

If the front of the drywall panel is recessed behind the front of the concrete, then a gap will form between baseboard's back and the drywall's front. You can get creative to fill it e.g. by applying two layers of baseboard effectively furring out the wall just for the baseboard, or adding a quarter round "crown" on top of the baseboard etc...

Depending on the moisture of the concrete it could be advisable to have a vapour barrier behind any drywall or baseboard that touches the concrete. You could use strips of vapour barrier plastic (6mil), or strips of sill plate foam plastic.

Those bottom few vertical inches do not require insulation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your photos at the moment, but there are two common ways that basement foundation half-walls are finished:

- Build a wall in front of or fur out the lower portion, including wrapping over the top for insulation.
- Build a full wall in front of the lower wall which extends to the ceiling.

Furring isn't usually done unless it's just on the lower half, and that's often more work than just building a wall. It won't suit your goal of a flat full-height wall anyway.

I'd remove what's there and build full-height walls if that's your goal.

Comment: huh interesting why you can't see the photos.
Anyway thanks for the answer. I guess I'll be building a full wall in front of the ledge. Question though, do I need to add another layer of insulation in front of already insulated and drywalled surface? Or should I take that out and add 2 layers of insulation?